# Keep connection to an API alive in python

Tags: python

I am developing a program to help me place orders faster on a cryptocurrency exchange (bitmex). It connects to the exchange, asks the user for some inputs and then asks the user for input in a loop (buy, sell, cancel or exit). Sometimes, when the exchange is overloaded it disconnects but i only know that it disconnected when i input something. Is there a way to constantly check if my program is connected and if not it tries to reconnect?

Here's the function that connects to the exchange:

```
class BitmexWrapper:
    # Handles BitMex connection and interaction
    orderBook = []

    def __init__(self, test, symbol):

        if (test == 'y'):
            self.client = bitmex.bitmex(test=True, api_key='',api_secret='')

        else:
            self.client = bitmex.bitmex(test=False, api_key='',api_secret='')

        self.mainLoop(symbol)
```

And here's the loop:

```
def mainLoop(self, symbol):
    #Asks the user to input the leverage and position size to be used on the trading session (INTRA-SESSION POSITION SIZE HANDLING TO BE IMPLEMENTED SOON)
    leverage = input("select your leverage (0-100)\n")
    self.client.Position.Position_updateLeverage(symbol=symbol, leverage=leverage).result()
    size = input("select your position size\n")
    getch = _Getch()

    #BitMex Interaction session
    while(True):
        call('clear')
        print("Press: l = long position / s = short position / c = cancel all orders / p = edit the position size / e = exit the program\n")
        userInput = getch.impl()

        if (userInput == 'l'):
            orderPrice = self.calculateMakerOrderPrice(symbol, 'Buy')
            self.client.Order.Order_new(symbol=symbol, orderQty = size, price = orderPrice).result()

        elif (userInput == 's'):
            orderPrice = self.calculateMakerOrderPrice(symbol,'Sell')
            self.client.Order.Order_new(symbol=symbol, side = 'Sell', orderQty = size, price = orderPrice).result()

        elif (userInput == 'c'):
            self.client.Order.Order_cancelAll(symbol=symbol).result()

        elif (userInput == 'p'):
            size = input("select your postion size\n")

        elif (userInput == 'e'):
            exit()

        else:
            print("Please enter a valid option.\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to create a thin wrapper around the api (or modify the api yourself) that catches the disconnect error and automatically tries to reconnect.  A lot of libraries that make use of OAuth tokens, which expire and have to be refreshed, do this.  They'll catch the expired token error and automatically refresh the token and retry the request.